# How to separate TCP socket messages in node.js

Tags: sockets, node.js

I'm cutting my teeth with TCP sockets and am confused with how messages are arriving to my app.  Seems like they are broken up.  Anyone know how I can best join them back together?  All messages are separated by a line break (\r\n)

```
var stream = net.createConnection(port,host); 
stream.setEncoding("utf8");

stream.on('data', function(chunk){
    console.log('data: ' + sys.inspect(chunk));
});
```

Sample of what dumps to the console looks like:

```
data: '0'
data: '5293800791D04\r'
data: '\n'
data: '053138007928F1\r\n'
data: '05313800012869\r\n'
data: '052E3800790E0E\r\n'
data: '052E3800010E86\r\n'
data: '05223'
data: '8007933F5\r\n'
data: '05213800791019\r\n'
data: '05213800795C795B79265A\r\n'
data: '05213800011091\r\n'
```

I need to break stuff up at the linebreak so I dont have incomplete messages.  Is there a way to tell node to do this for me?  If not, does anyone have any samples of how this might be done?

Answer (score 7):

I found a module called "carrier" which does exactly what I needed.  After installing the module it was as easy as adding this:

```
carrier.carry(stream, function(line) {
    console.log("line: "+line)
})
```

I found the answers here:

http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/5-a-basic-tcp-chat-server.html

https://github.com/pgte/carrier

Answer (score 5):

Since TCP is a *stream protocol* (and not a *block protocol*), it does not maintain any boundaries between what you might consider to be individual messages. This is the responsibility of the receiver if you need to reassemble high-level messages from an incoming stream.

You can do this by adding a layer that reads input data into a buffer, and then releases one line at a time whenever it sees a `\r\n` in the input stream.

As an aside, if you can change the stream data to have just *one* separator character (such as `\n` only), the buffering code might become a bit simpler.

Comment: You might want to say "messages" (an application-layer concept) instead of "data packets" (which has a specific meaning in TCP) to avoid confusion -- reassembling *data packets* into a stream is what TCP does.  Turning that stream into *messages* is something an application does.